# Best way to get random selection from DataTable?

Tags: .net, datatable, random

As the title says, what's the most efficient way to get a random selection of x DataRows from a DataTable.

Would it be to iteratively do something like the following until I have as many as I need?

```
protected DataRow SelectRandomRow(DataTable dataTable, Random randomSelector)
{
    return dataTable.Rows[randomSelector.Next(dataTable.Rows.Count)];
}
```

There must be a better way..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems like a perfectly reasonable option.

You'll probably want to add a check for duplicate rows being returned, however, as it could return the same row multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

Hope my solution is perfect...........

```
    Dim DT1 As New DataTable
    DT1.Columns.Add("SN1")
    DT1.Columns.Add("NAME1")
    DT1.Rows.Add("1", "Test1")
    DT1.Rows.Add("2", "Test2")
    DT1.Rows.Add("3", "Test3")
    DT1.Rows.Add("4", "Test4")
    DT1.Rows.Add("5", "Test5")
    DT1.Rows.Add("6", "Test6")
    DT1.Rows.Add("7", "Test7")
    DT1.Rows.Add("8", "Test8")
    DT1.Rows.Add("9", "Test9")
    DT1.Rows.Add("10", "Test10")
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DT1

    Dim DT2 As New DataTable
    DT2.Columns.Add("SN1")
    DT2.Columns.Add("NAME1")
    Dim I, CNT, J As Integer
    Dim RS As New Random

    While DT1.Rows.Count > 0
        CNT = DT1.Rows.Count - 1
        Try
            J = RS.Next(CNT)
            DT2.Rows.Add(DT1.Rows(J)("SN1"), DT1.Rows(RS.Next(CNT))("NAME1"))
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
        DT1.Rows.RemoveAt(J)
    End While
    DataGridView2.DataSource = DT2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For a random drug testing system I was working on, I actually went one step back to the query of qualified records and added a random() column as a column in the result set, and ordered by that column.

select randomFunction() as RandSequence, otherfields from table order by 1

Since a random is based on an original seed, and it not going to be run at the exact same time, same second, based on probability and human interjection, it worked great.  I ran the query like 50,000 times against the same "pool" of people -- one such group had over 800 people, and I stored the results.  At any given time, a person was only ever in the exact same position only about 4 times, but based totally on the decimal precision difference.

Then, you can always take the top X records directly from your result set.